# Past Participle (Looked after carefully)

Tags: grammar

> Looked after carefully, these boots will last for many years.

If it is transformed to relative clause, then what should be?

> These boots will last for many years, which should be looked after carefully.

Or something else?

Comment: This past participle allows more a conditional interpretation: _**If they are looked after carefully, ...**_

Comment: @ fev All right.

Comment: I am not saying a relative is impossible: _**These boots that are looked after carefully, will last for many years.**_ But the conditional meaning is really strong.

Comment: The general statement is: Boots that are looked after carefully will last for many years.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can answer this, and I hope that it's what you are looking for.  I believe that the sentence you want is:

*'These boots will last for many years **if** looked after carefully.'*

I'll try to explain why.

Your first sentence

> Looked after carefully, these boots will last for many years.

Is made of up two clauses, The first (Looked after carefully) is dependent and the second (these boots will last for many years) is independent.   Without a conjunction the relationship between the two clauses is controlled by their order.   The second is true because of the first.

However, if you rearrange the order of the clauses and don't include the correct conjunction then this meaning is lost.

> These boots will last for many years, *which* should be looked after
> carefully.

There are two mistakes here, the first was as I said reversing the order, and the second was adding the wrong conjunction.   'Which' implies an if/then relationship, so the sentence is saying that the boots should be looked after carefully **because** they have lasted many years.  This may be true if they are antiques or heirlooms or belonged to Elvis it something, but I don't think that's your meaning!

I hope this helps, In my opinion learning how clauses come together and form meaning is one of the hardest parts of English to learn.

Comment: if you rewrite the sentence as "These boots will last for many years, which should be looked after carefully," then the meaning is that the *years* should be looked after carefully!